# Werkzeug Bug --> 500 error (REQUEST) Odoo V10 - Ubuntu 16.04 - VPS Server

Tags: request, ubuntu-16.04, odoo-10, internal-server-error, werkzeug

It is my first bug with Odoo. I'm with a Ubuntu 16.04 - VPS server. Could I get some help?

2017-11-27 14:53:53,065 1473 INFO odooperso werkzeug: 88.127.184.173 - - [27/Nov/2017 14:53:53] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 - 2017-11-27 14:53:53,080 1473 ERROR odooperso werkzeug: Error on request:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 177, in run_wsgi

```
execute(self.server.app)
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 165, in execute

```
application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
```

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/server.py", line 249, in app

```
return self.app(e, s)
```

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 186, in application

```
return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
```

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 172, in application_unproxied

```
result = handler(environ, start_response)
```

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 1308, in **call**

```
return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
```

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 1282, in **call**

```
return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 588, in **call**

```
return self.app(environ, start_response)
```

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 1464, in dispatch odoo.registry(db).check_signaling()

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/**init**.py", line 52, in registry

```
return modules.registry.Registry(database_name)
```

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 59, in **new**

```
return cls.new(db_name)
```

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 82, in new

```
odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
```

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 335, in load_modules

```
force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module)
```

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 237, in load_marked_modules

```
loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
```

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 159, in load_module_graph

```
_load_data(cr, module_name, idref, mode, kind='demo')
```

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 95, in _load_data

```
tools.convert_file(cr, module_name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
```

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 845, in convert_file

```
convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
```

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 915, in convert_xml_import

```
obj.parse(doc.getroot(), mode=mode)
```

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 799, in parse

```
self._tags[rec.tag](rec, de, mode=mode)
```

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 707, in _tag_record

```
id = self.env(context=rec_context)['ir.model.data']._update(rec_model, self.module, res, rec_id or False, not self.isnoupdate(data_node), noupdate=self.isnoupdate(data_node), mode=self.mode)
```

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1229, in _update

```
record = record.create(values)
```

File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/hr_expense/models/product_template.py", line 18, in create

```
return super(ProductTemplate, self).create(vals)
```

File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/product/models/product_template.py", line 267, in create

```
template = super(ProductTemplate, self).create(vals)
```

File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/mail/models/mail_thread.py", line 228, in create

```
thread = super(MailThread, self).create(values)
```

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py", line 3826, in create

```
record = self.browse(self._create(old_vals))
```

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py", line 3921, in _create

```
cr.execute(query, tuple(u[2] for u in updates if len(u) > 2))
```

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/sql_db.py", line 154, in wrapper

```
return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/sql_db.py", line 231, in execute

```
res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
```

ParseError: "null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains (265, null, 1.00, null, 1, null, 1, 1, null, null, 2017-11-27 14:53:49.500906, 1, t, t, null, 1, 1, null, null, null, 2017-11-27 14:53:49.500906, t, 1, null, f, consu, no-message, null, manual, order, no, null, empty, null, null, 1, null, null, null, f, 1, 10, f, null, null, 0, null, none, null, f, t, null, null, null, null, f).

" while parsing /odoo/odoo-server/addons/website_sale/data/demo.xml:642, near

```
        <field name="public_categ_ids" eval="[(6,0,[ref('Computer_all_in_one')])]"/>

    </record>
```

Thank in advance,

Comment: When did this happen? When you have installed website_sale?

Comment: This has happened when I was in developper mode making an update of the website module.                                                                                              I have done that, because I was cleaning a dirty addons installation which was installed manually because I didni' find the way to install it with Pimp.

Comment: The error says that there a required field that you are not filling. Actually it seems that you are inserting or updating the demo data of the `website_sale` module